# Joining across 3000+ tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, strange one here

I have a database for customer data. My customers are businesses with their own customers.

I have 3000 tables (one for each business) with several thousand email addresses in each. Each table is identical, save the name.

I need to find a way to find where emails cross over between businesses (ie appear in multiple tables) and the name of the table that they sit in.

I have tried collating all entries and table names into one table and using a "group by", but the volume of data is too high to run this without our server keeling over...

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish this without running 3000 sets of joins?

Also, I cannot change the data structure AT ALL.

Thanks

EDIT: In response to those "helpful" restructure comments, not my database, not my system, I only started a couple of months ago to analyse the data

Comment: *Does anyone have a suggestion* YES! Stop making tables for businesses. Use a single table!

Comment: You need to change the structure. What you have done is created tables instead of rows. Bad idea!

Comment: Why would you want to _join_ those tables? It sounds as if you actually want a `UNION` or even `UNION ALL`

Comment: I know you say you can't restructure your data/tables at all but from what you are saying the database is in serious need of restructuring in order to normalize everything which will reduce the storage requirements and vastly improve performance. As of now you will need join or union all of the tables together

Comment: Find the person who designed this monstrosity and punch them in the head. Second tell management this structure has to be changed as it is completely asinine. Third if management refuses then find a new job as this one cannot possibly be paying you enough to put up with this level of incompetence.

Comment: If your server is barfing due to the sheer volume of data you may be able to optimize it.  Unless you want to check each table against each other table (a very slow process), you need to combine those emails into a table.  If you use an int identity column, you could have another table linking that int id to an int key for the table names that it is in.  Loop through each table and add the email or fetch the existing id from table 1 and add the email id and table id to table 2.  Then you can count the table ids for a given email id in that table and find the email addresses.

Comment: `Each table is identical, save the name.` Then merge the tables and add a `name` field (or a foreign key). Problem solved.

Comment: it's idiotic designs like this that feed the ridiculous notion of "JOINS BAD!!! NOSQL GOOOOD!!!" when the RDBMS is a tool in the hands of developers without a clue, then i guess it stands no chance.

Comment: All up, how many email addresses are there?

Comment: If you are there to analyse the data shouldn't you also be analyzing the data and table structures to ensure they are not potentially causing harm to the system?

Answer (score 3):

Multiple tables of identical structure almost never makes sense, all it would take is a `business` field to fix this structure.  If at all possible you should fix the structure. If it has been foisted upon you and you cannot change it, you should still be able to work with it.

Select the distinct emails and the table name from each table either `UNION  ALL` or pull them into a new table, then use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find emails with multiple tables.

```
SELECT email
FROM Combined_Table
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(sourc_table) > 1
```

Comment: Insert all the data into one table and use the query above.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I initially went with. Sadly, the server was unable to cope with the massive dataset

Comment: @JohnHC Did you try to `UNION` them all at once?  If you go table by table and insert the distinct emails into a new table this shouldn't be that taxing.

Comment: @JohnHC . . . If the one table solution didn't work at first, you took the wrong approach to fixing it.  The first two things that come to mind are indexing the table and using multiple partitions for storage.  Breaking up the table would be a last resort and typically only done for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

So, you say you can't change the data structure, but you might be able to provide a compatible upgrade.

1. Provide a new mega table:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE business_email (
        id_business INT(10) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY id_business, email
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM;
   ```

Myisam engine so you don't have to worry about transactions.

1. Add a trigger to every single business table to duplicate the email into the new one:

   ```
   DELIMITER \\

   CREATE TRIGGER TRG_COPY_EMAIL_BUSINESS1 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON business1 FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO `business_email` (`id_business`, `email`) VALUES (NEW.`id_business`, NEW.`email`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id_business`=NEW.`id_business`;
   END;
   \\

   DELIMITER ;
   ```

Your problem is to add it dynamically whenever a new table is created. It shouldn't be a problem since apparently there's already dynamic DDL in your application code.

1. Copy all existing data to the new table:

   ```
   INSERT INTO `business_email` (`id_business`, `email`) 
   SELECT email FROM business1
   UNION
   SELECT email FROM business2
   ...
   ;

   COMMIT;
   ```
2. proceed with your query on the new `business_email` table, that should be greatly simplified:

   ```
   SELECT `id_business` FROM `business_email` 
   WHERE
   GROUP BY `email`
   HAVING COUNT(`email`) > 2;
   ```

This query should be easy to cope with. If not, please detail the issue as I don't think properly indexed tables should be a problem even for millions of rows (Which I don't believe is the case since we talk about emails)

The advantage of this solution is that you stay up to date all the time, while you don't change the way your application works. You just add another layer to provide additional business value.